# Filter in dplyr if condition is met across ANY variable within a row

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Take the following tiny dataframe.

```
df = tribble(
~col1,~col2,~col3,
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9
)
```

I want to filter rows where ANY value is less than 5. The following doesn't work but was my initial thought:

```
df %>%
filter(across(
    .fns = ~.<5
))
```

The output for that, however, is

```
1 , 2 , 3
```

instead of the expected output of

```
1 , 2 , 3,
4 , 5 , 6
```

While there is a solution by not using `across()` and filtering using `filter(col1 < 5 | col2 < 5 | col3 < 5)`, I would like to learn of a more generalizable approach for larger datasets that could be used with `all_of()` or `everything()`.

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: If you want any value in a row to be less than 5, why would your expected output has a row of `4,5,6`?  5 and 6 don't meet your criterion right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Use `rowSums`

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(. < 5) > 0)
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##    col1  col2  col3
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     2     3
## 2     4     5     6
```

**2)** or `Reduce`

```
df %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, as.data.frame(. < 5)))
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##    col1  col2  col3
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     2     3
## 2     4     5     6
```

Replace dot with `select(., ...whatever...)` or just use ordinary subscripting if you want to only consider certain columns.

**3)** or use `c_across`

```
df %>% rowwise %>% filter(any(c_across() < 5))
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##    col1  col2  col3
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     2     3
## 2     4     5     6
```

Comment: Thank you! To expand on this a bit, assuming that the cells were characters/strings and we want any row that has the character '5', would `df %>% rowwise %>% filter(any(str_detect(c_across(),'5')))` be the way to go? At least with `str_detect` the other methods do not work (they do work with a simple `==` though. Thank you again!

Comment: Use unlist: `df2 <- data.frame(a = c("12", "34"), b = c("56", "78"))
df2 %>% rowwise %>% filter(any(grepl("5", unlist(c_across()))))`

Comment: Thank you @g-grothendieck! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier we could use `filter_all` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. < 5))
```

However, since `filter_all` is deprecated we can combine `Reduce` with `across`.

```
df %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns = ~. < 5)))

#   col1  col2  col3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3
#2     4     5     6
```

Comment: This is great! Will test these options out at some point. Appreciate the help.