# Using any with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, any

How can I use `any` in a dplyr pipeline ?

I want to extract rows with at least one `TRUE`.

```
mydata = data.frame(V1=c(FALSE,NA,FALSE,TRUE),
                    V2 = c(NA,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
                    V3 = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))

mydata

     V1    V2    V3
1 FALSE    NA FALSE
2    NA  TRUE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: `subset(mydata, rowSums(mydata, na.rm = T) >0)`

Comment: @AnilGoyal thanks for the comment,
I have other vars in my data frame the above is just a reproducible example

Comment: So use mydata[1:3] inside rowsums

Comment: Maybe question would be better phrased as "How can I use `any` across columns with dplyr?" or something like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147191/filter-in-dplyr-if-condition-is-met-across-any-variable-within-a-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `rowwise` and `c_across` if using `any`, but as pointed out by @akrun, the function `if_any` nicely combines these elements.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mydata <- data.frame(
    V1 = c(FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE),
    V2 = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
    V3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))

mydata %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    filter(any(c_across(starts_with("V")))) %>%
    ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 NA    TRUE  FALSE
#> 2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

mydata %>% 
    filter(if_any(starts_with("V")))
#>     V1   V2    V3
#> 1   NA TRUE FALSE
#> 2 TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We can use `if_any` in a vectorized way

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with('V')))
    V1   V2    V3
1   NA TRUE FALSE
2 TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

As a specific solution to your question, try below.

```
x <- mydata %>% filter(V1 | V2 | V3)
```

Comment: Edited the question: no need to compare the logicals: `filter(V1)` instead of `filter(V1 == TRUE)`.